# MoveIt arm_navigation_msgs compatible, how to port?

Tags: ros, moveit, kuka

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm new to ROS so this is perhaps a newbie question, sorry about that.

I'm trying to connect our kuka 850 to ROS, and came across a third party stack on git (cant post link yet, here is with spaces inserted) https://github.com/uobirlab/kuka.

The manifest lists arm_navigation_msgs as a dependency, but wiki says this is deprecated and to use MoveIt instead.
My options are then to try and build the stack as is, or port it to MoveIt.

1. Is arm_navigation_msgs compatible with MoveIt? If I build it with for example the arm_navigation source on git would it work with MoveIt? Or should I just install Fuerte to run this?
2. What would normally have to be changed to port this to MoveIt, can you give me some hints where to look?

Currently running ROS Hydro Medusa on Ubuntu 13.04.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/175197/moveit-arm_navigation_msgs-compatible,-how-to-port?/) by [matheusz](https://answers.ros.org/users/19018/matheusz/) on ROS Answers with karma: 90 on 2014-06-27

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) on 2014-06-27**:
Post the link with some spaces in it -- I can make it a link for you.

**Comment by [matheusz](https://answers.ros.org/users/19018/matheusz/) on 2014-06-28**:
Added link, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

MoveIt completely replaces arm_navigation, and there is no bridge between the two. Moveit does have a setup assistant that makes it easy to generate most of the required configuration once you have a URDF for the robot (the controller stuff is not generated automatically, but the moveit google mailing list has some examples).

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2014-06-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [matheusz](https://answers.ros.org/users/19018/matheusz/) on 2014-06-28**:
Thanks for that info! There is a URDF file included which hopefully works. Looks like I will test it first on Fuerte and later rewrite it completely for MoveIt in Hydro.